# Avoid duplicates without distinct

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, distinct

Is there a way to make the query to return only one record without using distinct ?

> ```
> CREATE TABLE users (
>     id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     registration_number INT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
>     name VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY(id)
> );
>
> CREATE TABLE tickets (
>     id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     title VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
>     description TEXT,
>     PRIMARY KEY(id)
> );
>
> CREATE TABLE tickets_requesters (
>     tickets_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
>     users_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
> );
>
> CREATE TABLE tickets_recipients (
>     tickets_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
>     users_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
> );
>
> INSERT INTO users 
>   (name, registration_number)
> VALUES
>   ('Paul', 12),
>   ('John', 34);
>   
>   
> INSERT INTO tickets
>   (title)
> VALUES
>   ('Ticket #1'),
>   ('Ticket #2');
>   
>   
> INSERT INTO tickets_requesters
>   (tickets_id, users_id)
> VALUES
>   (1, 1),
>   (1, 2);
>   
> INSERT INTO tickets_recipients
>   (tickets_id, users_id)
> VALUES
>   (1, 1);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
> t.id,
> t.title
> FROM tickets t
> LEFT JOIN tickets_requesters trq ON trq.tickets_id = t.id
> LEFT JOIN tickets_recipients trc ON trc.tickets_id = t.id
> LEFT JOIN users urq ON urq.id = trq.users_id
> LEFT JOIN users urc ON urc.id = trc.users_id
> WHERE (urq.registration_number = 12 OR urc.registration_number = 12);
> ```

> ```
> id | title    
> -: | :--------
>  1 | Ticket #1
>  1 | Ticket #1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=0ee7cfe59c6741d3b3471c43e5b4bbd9)*

**EDIT :**

Thanks to all for your answers.
So far there are 3 ways to do it :

- With `group by`
- With `union`
- With `exists`

So, is there a specific use case for each of these methods or can I use either one ?

Comment: `group by t.id,t.title;`

Comment: why did you need to `join` `users` table twice?

Comment: Also note: your left joins are negated on your users table due to the where clause.  (in essence the joins will behave like INNER JOINs due to the  limits imposed in the where clause for those two tables.)

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: Why don't you want to use DISTINCT?

Comment: @AndyLester It's not that I don't want to. It's more like I want to know how to do it without it

Answer (score 3):

You could use `EXISTS` instead of the joins:

```
SELECT t.id, t.title
FROM tickets t
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM tickets_requesters trq INNER JOIN users urq 
        ON urq.id = trq.users_id
        WHERE trq.tickets_id = t.id AND urq.registration_number = 12
      )
   OR EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM tickets_requesters trc INNER JOIN users urc 
        ON urc.id = trc.users_id
        WHERE trc.tickets_id = t.id AND urc.registration_number = 12
      );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION` to combine the two kinds of condition you're looking for.

```
SELECT t.id, t.title
FROM tickets t
JOIN tickets_requesters trq ON trq.tickets_id = t.id
JOIN users urq ON urq.id = trq.users_id
WHERE urq.registration_number = 12 
UNION
SELECT t.id, t.title
FROM tickets t
JOIN tickets_recipients trc ON trc.tickets_id = t.id
JOIN users urc ON urc.id = trc.users_id
WHERE urc.registration_number = 12;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=6bbfcb9855cf2e3e65df16a14f7af9d4)

Comment: thanks for the remarks. I edited my question for the first

Comment: Creative... but union just hides the distinct right?  `UNION` (does a  distinct) `UNION ALL` Does not.